# Microsoft Edge - close tab on back button

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, browser-tabs, tabs

I believe this may have been on a previous installation of Windows 11, so I am unsure if this is a new feature for that OS or not. However, I really liked this function and was wondering if anybody was able to replicate it for Microsoft Edge on Windows 10.

**If you have "open results in a new tab" enabled on Bing and click on the *Back* button for those new tab pages, it closes the tab and brings you back to the results page.**
The issue is, now when I click the Back button on the opened tab from search results, it stays on the same tab and takes me back to the search results, leaving me with 2 tabs with the same search results.

Is there a setting that accomplishes this? Is this specific to Windows 11? I have looked through both Bing and browser settings but have not found anything that controls this behavior.

Comment: The setting would either exist in Edge or Bing what you describe is NOT a Windows 11 feature

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Recent versions of IE had OS specific features, which is leading me to believe it was just a Windows 11 feature.